# What happens if a C program running in a docker container requests more memory than is allowed to the container?

Tags: c, docker

Let's say I create a docker container with specified memory limit as follows:

```
docker run -d --memory="256m" nginx
```

I then run commands and programs on this container. If a C program running in the container requests more memory than 256MB, (let's say 1GB), I imagine one of these things will happen, although I am not sure which:
1) The container will enter an OOM state, triggering itself to kill the process requesting the extra memory.
2) The extra 768MB will be provided (as virtual memory for the program), but the pages will be stored on disk or in swap space, rather than RAM.
3) The container will simply return a NULL pointer to the C program's mmap/malloc call.

What determines which of these things, if any, would actually occur?

Comment: Wouldn't that be pretty simple to test yourself to find out what happens?

Comment: I am not so much interested in knowing what will happen in a specific instance nearly as much as I am in knowing what factors will determine the answer to the above. It would seem unreasonable to draw conclusions from a test run if there are many variables that actually affected what would happen.

Comment: If the instance is started with the specific parameters you provided above, it's not going to behave inconsistently. It's going to do the same thing every time, because the same container being started the same way consistently isn't going to change.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) this depends on the OS and other factors listed there.  Given the poor quality of the available documentation, I would suggest that some experimentation might be in order.  Your app should always be prepared to handle out of memory conditions.